# Finding joint probability function of Bernoulli and Discrete uniform.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

X is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter p

and Y is a discrete uniform random variable that assumes the values 1, 2 and 3.

I am trying to find the distribution of (X,Y) without assuming independence between X and Y. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the joint distribution then that is your answer.  But if not then no.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're looking for a distribution of $X$ and $Y$ for which the marginals are Bernoulli and discrete, respectively. Suppose $a, b, c, d, e, f$ are all nonnegative and add to one, and think about distributions looking like
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\bf{X=0} & a & b & c \\
\bf{X=1} & d & e & f \\
& \bf{Y=1} & \bf{Y=2} & \bf{Y=3}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: You know $d+e+f=p$ and $a+b+c=1-p$, and no more